# If I declare a package with multiple levels of embedding, does the module named as the leaf node need to be in a subdirctory?

Tags: perl, package

I am dealing with some legacy Perl code, which I want to change as little as possible. The main script, call it "myscript.pl" has a structure like this

```
use MyCompany::ABDoc::HTMLFile;
use MyCompany::ABDoc::JavaScriptFile 2014.004_015;

print "Howdy"
...
```

The HTMLFile.pm module looks like this

```
package MyCompany::AMDoc::HTMLFile;

...
```

I am troubleshooting my_script.pl, and wish to run it from the command line. (It normally is triggered by a Jenkins job). When I try

```
perl -d ./my_script.pl
```

I get a message about HTMLFile.pm not being found. This is because hte HTMLFile.pm actually exists at the same level as my_script.pl in the filesystem.

If this was my own script, and I had the freedom to move things around, I would create directory structure

MyCompany/AMDoc/HtmlFile.pm

and I know the script would work. But I am reluctant to do this, because somehow, this all runs fine when triggered by the Jenkins job.

So is it possible to run this code, from the command line, without moving anything? I just want to do some troubleshooting. I haven't found discussion in the Perl documentation about what kinds of command line flags, such as "-I", might help me out here.

Comment: Are you sure the Jenkins job doesn't have another copy somewhere? You should be able to read its definition to see how it runs the script. There are advanced ways how to make it work, but I doubt they're in place.

Comment: As far as I know, you do need the path `MyCompany/AMDoc/HtmlFile.pm` to actually exist, available from the base dir of the paths in `@INC`. Otherwise it would just load any file with the right name. Are you sure it is not available somewhere else in the `@INC` path? Try `perl -lwe'for (@INC) { for (glob "$_/MyCompany/AMDoc/*") { print }}'`

Comment: What does the following output on the server? `perl -le'use MyCompany::AMDoc::HTMLFile; print $INC{"MyCompany/AMDoc/HTMLFile.pm"};'`

Answer (score 0):

> I would create directory structure `MyCompany/AMDoc/HtmlFile.pm` and I know the script would work.

No, moving the file to `MyCompany/AMDoc/HTMLFile.pm` relative to the script would not work unless the script already takes steps to add its directory to `@INC`.<sup>[1]</sup>

For example, adding the following in the script would achieve that:

```perl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
```

This can also be done from without

```sh
perl -I "$dir" "$dir"/my_script.pl    # General case

perl -I . ./my_script.pl              # Specific case
```

> So is it possible to run this code, from the command line, without moving anything?

No, not without modifying the script.<sup>[2]</sup>

According to what you gave us, it has to be accessible as `MyCompany/AMDoc/HTMLFile.pm` relative to a directory in `@INC`.

---

1. It would happen to work if the script's current work directory happened to match the directory in which the script is found in old version of Perl. But that's just a fluke. These frequently don't match.
2. Well, you could use something of the form

   ```sh
   perl -e'
      use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
      my $s = shift;
      push @INC, sub {
         my ( undef, $path ) = @_;
         my ( $qfn ) = $path =~ m{^MyCompany/AMDoc/(.*)}s
            or return;
         open( my $fh, '<', $qfn )
            or return;
         return $fh;         
      };
      do( $s ) or die( $@ // $! );
   ' ./my_script.pl
   ```

   Even then, that expects the script to end in a true value.

Comment: so in other words "perl -I . ./my script.pl" should work? Because like I say, I just want to troublehoot it on the server, with minimal or no rewriting of the scrip. I will try some things, and come back and hopefully upvote your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this Can't locate MyCompany/AMDoc/HTMLFile.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./my_script.pl line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./my_script.pl line 27.

Comment: even though @INC contains "."

Comment: @egilchri Re "*so in other words `perl -I . ./my script.pl` should work?*", If you move the file, yes.

Comment: @egilchri Re "*Unfortunately, I get this*", Does `./MyCompany/AMDoc/HTMLFile.pm` exist?

Comment: The file HTMLFile.pm exists, but at the same level as the script. It is not in a subdirectory. It has a package declaration as described above.

Comment: It HTMLFIle.pm needs to be in a sub-directory, then I have a funny feeling this isn't running on the server I think it is. Because on the server where I think it's running, it's not in a sub-directory.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a subdirectory. But it does have to be accessible as `MyCompany/AMDoc/HTMLFile.pm` relative to a directory in `@INC`.

Comment: I'm closing this, because I figured it out. My script is running on a Kubernetes pod, and the way the pod is configured, the package statements work.  That's because the ENV variable PERL5LIB is set. So the proper paths are set in one of the included directories.

Answer (score 0):

My initial assumption was wrong. My code was actually running on a Kubernetes pod, and that pod was configured with the correct directory structure for the module. In addition, PERL5LIB is set in the pod.

```
PERL5LIB=/perl5lib/perl-modules:/perl5lib/perl-modules/cpan/lib64/perl5:/perl5lib/perl-modules/cpan/share/perl5
```

and sure enough, that very first path has the path to my module.